# How to save vimeo video offline which is only playable by Ionic 4 app

Tags: ionic-framework, video, ionic4, offline, vimeo

Using Ionic 4, Is there any way to implement a functionality to save vimeo video offline which is only playable through my Ionic app (like Youtube, Vimeo, Hotstar app).

I have tried to download videos in `dataDirectory` as below, But while doing R&D I found out that `dataDirectory` data will not be visible in android, Only root access can see it. And in iOS it can be edited without root.

```
  fileTransfer.download(uri, this.file.dataDirectory + 'media/' + 
    filename).then((entry) => {}, 
    (error) => {});
```

So can any one please let me know what can be the best way to implement offline functionality where there is no risk of data accessibility ?

Comment: What work have you already attempted? Read the article here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @TommyPenner Thank you, I have tried to work on your advice.

Comment: @Darshana have you found anything ? by the way by which path you are getting download URL?

Comment: @RaviMehta  I have added '&download=1' at the end of URL.